# Reading a line up to a certain amount of data

Tags: c#

Im creating an application which will read in a large data file and return a specific selection of text from each line in a .dat file. Please see example of the data below.

> 22/06/2016    22:18:21.209    Type6   -92.31435   2.06424 0.07686
>   22/06/2016    22:18:21.210    Type34  -91.4085    1.84464 -0.09333

I need the first 3 sets of data which is the date, time and type. The values after the type go on for a while and i have a large amount of rows which need to collected from. I have thought about just splitting each section of the line and taking the first 3 fields. Would this work or would there be an easier way to complete this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the length of one line?

Comment: have you tried to use Regex.Match method for each line? sample is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The length of one line is around 199 characters including spaces but it contains other data which may be longer or shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way (extracting just three fields); I suggest using *Linq* in the context, e.g.

```
 var source = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyData.dat")
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 4))
  .Where(items => items.Length >= 3) // it seems that you have empty lines or something
  .Select(items => new {
     // Let's combine date and time into DateTime
     date = DateTime.ParseExact(items[0] + " " + items[1], 
                                @"dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s.fff", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
     kind = items[2] });
// .ToArray(); // you may want add materialization (i.e. read once and put into array)
```

Having got this Linq query you can easily *filter out* and *represent* the data you want, e.g.

```
 var test = source
   .Where(item => item.date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)) // let's have fresh records only
   .OrderByDescending(item => item.date)
   .Select(item => $"{item.date} {item.kind}");

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, test));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i have run into a little issue when trying to implament your code please see the link below.

Comment: @Englishman: it seems that your file have *empty lines* or something like them, so splitting returns too few items (zero in case of empty line) and you have exception thrown on `items[2]` when asking for the 3d item. I suggest adding `.Where(items => items.Length >= 3)` in order to rule out such lines

Comment: Where should i place this as when i try to implement it in most places i get no values in my text box?

Comment: @Englishman: if you want to read *once* and then query *many* ("in most places i get no values"), add *materialization* (e.g. `.ToArray()`).

Answer (score 0):

You could make something just to read the first chars of each line, but the length of the line is not specified anywhere, so you have to read all the data.

You should use `File.ReadLines(path)` because it is lazy loading the data. This will only load one line per iteration. Foreach line you should check what data you need and save it on whatever you like...

```
var relevantData = new List<T>();
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    // parse the data you need.
    relevantData.Add( new T { Date = whatever, ..... });
}
```

---

If you need to parse it multiple times, you could create an index file that contains the start index of each line.